# How to display values with zero frequency on plotly histogram x-axis?

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I have the simple dataframe `d` below and I want to create a histogram based on the frequency of its values. I am trying to set the inital value as `0` and then display the values in the x-axis by `5` but neither of those seems to work since values begin from `1` and then display `8`. I found out that this happens because my dataframe does not have `2` and `3` as values so the counting stops at `1` and begings from `4` until `8` because my dataframe includes `4,5,6,7,8` as values so the counting stops normally.

The solutions might be 2. The first one to find a way to display values with zero frequency on the axis and the second to set the correct tick formating without those values on the axis.

I would prefer a clear plotly solution on this as first choice, without `ggplot()` interference.

[image]

```
d<-data.frame(c(1,5,7,5,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,15,13))
x <- list(
  tick0=0,
  dtick=5

)

# Create the plotly histogram

plot_ly(alpha = 0.9) %>%
  add_histogram(x = as.factor(d[,1]),source="subset") %>%
  # Add titles in plot and axes
  layout(barmode = "overlay",xaxis=x,margin=list(b=100))
```

Comment: Do you perchance get what you want by omitting the `as.factor()`: ie `add_histogram(x = d[,1],source="subset") %>%` ?

Comment: add_histogram(x = d[,1], xbins = list(start=0, end=20, size=1)) %>%

Comment: thanks @tasasaki it works like this but without the gaps between the bars but it is good. Just removing rhe factor was creatin bars with range of values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a trick, using `categoryorder = "array"` and `categoryarray = x_axis_values` in xaxis layout. With these you can manually set the values that xaxis will contain.

I had modified a little your example of code, but this should do the trick:

```
# yours data
d = c(1,5,7,5,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,15,13)

# Create the plotly histogram

plot_ly(alpha = 0.9) %>%
  add_histogram(x = as.character(d)
                ) %>%
  # Add titles in plot and axes
  layout(barmode = "overlay",
         margin=list(b=100),
         # Set the xaxis values
         xaxis=list(categoryorder="array",
                    categoryarray = as.character(min(d):max(d))
                    )
        )
```

Here the output:

[image]